# UWP - Why is my simple animation not running

Tags: animation, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am totally lost at the moment. What is wrong with my animation? Why is it not running? Any help would be highly appreciated! I want to develop sort of an circular progress bar which is "rolling in" as if the bar was filled up.

The following code runs inside an empty UWP app in the MainPage's Loaded Handler. Nothing else...

```
ArcSegment myArcSegment = new ArcSegment();
myArcSegment.Size = new Size(90, 80);
myArcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;

PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
myPathSegmentCollection.Add(myArcSegment);

PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();

myPathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(100, 200);

myPathFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

PathFigureCollection myPathFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
myPathFigureCollection.Add(myPathFigure);

PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
myPathGeometry.Figures = myPathFigureCollection;

Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;

myPath.Data = myPathGeometry;

PointAnimation mySizeAnimation = new PointAnimation();
mySizeAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

mySizeAnimation.From = new Point(90, 80);
mySizeAnimation.To = new Point(500, 200);

Storyboard.SetTarget(mySizeAnimation, myArcSegment);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mySizeAnimation, nameof(ArcSegment.Point));

Storyboard ellipseStoryboard = new Storyboard();
ellipseStoryboard.Children.Add(mySizeAnimation);

myPath.Loaded += delegate (object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ellipseStoryboard.Begin();
};

Canvas containerCanvas = new Canvas();
containerCanvas.Children.Add(myPath);

Content = containerCanvas;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my... I just read this post: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-animated-pie-slice.html

By accident I read about the ***EnableDependendAnimation*** Property... never heared of it, but Setting it to true just made the Animation run. I will read up on that now. Thanks anyways!